# How do I position divs / cards like this?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble position divs like the ones in the photo.

[image]

```
 <div class="cards" id="cards">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="single">
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="single">


          <span class="dot"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="second">
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="second">
          <span class="dot"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I've tried it like this but I've had trouble styling and positioning it with css.

Single divs are named the first two cards / divs up.
Second divs are named the second cards / divs down.

Comment: What's your CSS?

Comment: I've tried several things but I didnt get any success at all. I get to the point where I position the two first cards perfectly on the left, but the bottom ones I cant move them. I came to the point where I deleted all css and thought to ask for help.

Comment: Create 2 divs under each other, put 2 cards in each div,then give display: flex and justify-content: 'start' for the first div and 'end' the second. Also make sure the divs has the same width! That should do the trick - however, pay attention as we don't know your CSS code, so there could be other things that you might need to adjust.

Comment: @Geilmaker because Stack Overflow is generally not a place for people to write your code for you. We want to see what you have tried so that we can show you the proper adjustments and teach you where exactly you went wrong and why.

Answer (score 1):

CSS Grid can help you with these types of layouts. Study the code below to see how you can lay out the boxes according to the mockup.

Make sure to carefully study the following section on MDN about `Grid template areas`: [Leaving a grid cell empty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_grid_layout/Grid_template_areas)

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.strategy {
  grid-area: strategy;
}
.efficient {
  grid-area: efficient;
}
.fast {
  grid-area: fast;
}
.reliable {
  grid-area: reliable;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
  grid-template-areas:
    "fast efficient ." /* 3 cols: fast / efficient / . === empty col */
    ". strategy reliable";
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper">
  <div class="fast">Fast</div>
  <div class="efficient">Efficient</div>
  <div class="strategy">Strategy</div>
  <div class="reliable">Reliable</div>
</section>
```

**Resources:** [Complete Guide to CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)